# Is there a way to bookmark a wordpad or word file where you left off?

Tags: microsoft-word, wordpad

I work with very long .rtf and .doc files and am constantly opening/closing them. Is there a way to save where I am at in the file so when I reopen I'm back to that same spot?

Comment: Please put effort into your questions, eg spelling, grammer, english, etc.

Comment: TheLQ: It's spelt 'grammar' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law! His spelling and grammar are fine anyway. It's his punctuation that is the problem.

Comment: Office 2013 has this feature built-in, it prompts you to continue where you left off when you open the file. I imagine the feature remains in 2016.

Answer (score 3):

### For MS Word (if you cannot modify the file),

1. Jot down the page number where you left
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (Go To) > Page > Enter page number > <kbd>Go To</kbd>

---

### For Wordpad,

I would second Kara Marfia's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/198038/43356):

1. Enter some special characters (like `~!~`) at where you left
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (Find) to search the special characters

---

### For MS Word (if you can modify the file),

1. Highlight the paragraph or place the cursor at the location you want to bookmark
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> (Bookmark)
3. Type a name for your bookmark then click <kbd>Add</kbd>.

   [image: Insert Bookmark]
4. Next time you open the document, use either of:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> (Bookmark) > Choose bookmark > <kbd>Go To</kbd>
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (Go To) > Bookmark > Choose bookmark in drop-down > <kbd>Go To</kbd>

   [image: Go To]

([ref](http://www.worldstart.com/tips/tips.php/834), [ref](http://www.ehow.com/how_2093405_add-bookmark-microsoft-word.html))

Answer (score 0):

A ghetto approach would be to simply highlight the whole paragraph you were working on with pink or some other kind of visible color. Then when you reopen the file just scroll through the whole document with the scroll bar and stop when you get to the huge highlighted section (it will stand out).

Answer (score 0):

You could type in a unique set of characters that aren't likely to exist elsewhere in the document (such as ~!~) to mark your spot, then skip to it with Find.

Answer (score 0):

In Word, it is easy to jump back to the last *edit* with `Shift+F5` if as soon as document is opened [see here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/return-to-your-last-editing-location-when-you-open-a-word-document/810).