# How to save a position in a document for easy return?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, documents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to bookmark a wordpad or word file where you left off?](https://superuser.com/questions/197981/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-a-wordpad-or-word-file-where-you-left-off)
>   [Is there a way to insert an internal anchor/bookmark into MS Word document and later reference it?](https://superuser.com/questions/378927/is-there-a-way-to-insert-an-internal-anchor-bookmark-into-ms-word-document-and-l)

How to save the position in a document so that I can return to that exact position easily later?

For example when I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click on an internal link in a Word document, it takes me to the target of that link, losing my original position. Or when I search for something woth <kbd>F3</kbd> from a certain position, it jumps to the next occurence of the term. Every time I find it rather painful to get back to the position in the document where I've started from. Of course this is no issue for small documents, but for hundreds of pages, scanning back to the desired page could take some time. Now I am aware of the fact that I can check/enter the actual page number in Word, but I am looking for a both a general solution for other documents and a solution that can be activated by simple keystrokes.

Is there a general method to handle such nuisances by e.g. saving a certain position in a document with a keystroke which I can use later to return that position? Maybe multiple positions saved with different keys? Is there a general method to handle .doc, .pdf, .txt, or any other file, perhaps even webpages displayed by a browser? If there is no general way to do this, perhaps only in Microsoft Word?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to bookmark a wordpad or word file where you left off?](http://superuser.com/questions/197981/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-a-wordpad-or-word-file-where-you-left-off) and/or [Is there a way to insert an internal anchor/bookmark into MS Word document and later reference it?](http://superuser.com/questions/378927/is-there-a-way-to-insert-an-internal-anchor-bookmark-into-ms-word-document-and-l)

Comment: Microsoft Word 2013 will support this feature.

Comment: @techie007: Sorry for the dupe, but actually two answers were provided here that are not listed in any of the links you have pointed. I find both answers highly relevant and Useful. Can these be migrated to those questions? Also, my question is about a general problem, not just MS Word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> -- Go back after clicking a hyperlink. (The "Web Toolbar" was gone in Word 2007.)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> -- Undo the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> -- Go back to previously edited location in document (up to 4 places)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> -- Go to a the last change or revision. Also works after opening document

You can also save a position in the document with a **bookmark**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> - Set, go to and edit bookmarks

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> - Go to a page, bookmark, footnote, table, comment, graphic, or other location

Comment: I assume these shortcuts are MS Office-specific.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to "split" screen the document. Just above the scroll bar on the right, you should have the mouse change to an up/down arrow, and you can drag that down.
[image]

Search on one pane, and leave the other where you want. 
[image]

Comment: This is only available since MS Word 2010, am I right? At least, it is not present in Office 2003.

Comment: @ist it worked for me on versions back to version 6.0, just before office 95